# redirect if cookie exists

Tags: php, redirect, cookies, httpcookie

i want to check, if a sso cookie is set.
The cookie checkups are in different applications.
My sso domain is something like cas.sso.example.com and my/our application domain is something like app.example.com or app.ex.example.com.

I used a short php script but it doesn't work.

```
<?php  
if( isset( $_COOKIE['cookiename']  ) ) 
{ 
     header('Location: '.$urlForAutoLogin);  
} 
?>
```

In my test enviroment is doesn't work. But i think it should...
can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_COOKIE);` ? What it prints?

Comment: Remember that the cookie is site-specific, so a cookie from one comain will not be included for another one (as your domains differ).